# Duplicate <link rel='preload'> and <script>, Browser warning to add "crossoriging" to link and "as" to script for Nuxt generated page sources

Tags: webpack, nuxt.js

Got a Nuxt project where I am getting errors about some preloaded files not having `crossorigin` and `as` parameters.

Not sure if it is a NUXT specific bug or some package?
I deleted all my preload and prefetch code to see if it will give any difference, but nothing changed.

[image]

asked same question in NUXT community https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/discussions/10612

[image]

After some research I found out that the problem is related to webpack and can be potentially fixed by output.crossOriginLoading
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/
Which I tried to apply in my nuxt.config.ts like so:

```
  target: "static", <-----tried both static and server
  output: {
    crossOriginLoading: "anonymous",
  },
```

Nothing works.
After navigating to the link in Chrome browser I can see that webpack's JSONP is used to build chunks.

```
window["webpackJsonp"] = window["webpackJsonp"]
```

Is it used by default in NUXT?

**UPDATE:**

Apparently I have script tags with "as" in the page source. Wondering why the warning still appearing in the console

```
 <link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/app~._.nuxt_A.js" as="script" />
    <link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/app~._.nuxt_A.css" as="style" />
    <link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/app~._a.css" as="style" />
    <link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/app~._a.js" as="script" />
    <link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/app~._l.js" as="script" />
    <link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/app~._layouts_d.js" as="script" />
    <link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/app~._n.js" as="script" />
    <link
      rel="preload"
      href="/_nuxt/app~._node_modules_atlas_node_modules_vue_dist_vue.runtime.esm.js~8cb01656.js"
      as="script"
    />
    <link
      rel="preload"
      href="/_nuxt/app~._node_modules_atlas_src_c.js"
      as="script"
    />
    <link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/app~._node_modules_ba.js" as="script" />
    <link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/app~._node_modules_c.js" as="script" />
    <link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/app~._node_modules_h.js" as="script" />
    <link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/app~._node_modules_i.js" as="script" />
    <link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/app~._node_modules_vue-c.js" as="script" />
    <link
      rel="preload"
      href="/_nuxt/app~._node_modules_vue_dist_vue.runtime.esm.js~6acccc03.js"
      as="script"
    />
    <link
      rel="preload"
      href="/_nuxt/header-bar-mobile-menu~._node_modules_atlas_src_components_HeaderBar_HeaderBarMobileMenu.vue~0.js"
      as="script"
    />
    <link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/pages/index~._c.css" as="style" />
    <link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/pages/index~._c.js" as="script" />
    <link
      rel="preload"
      href="/_nuxt/pages/_~pages/index~pages/preview/_~pages/search~._c.js"
      as="script"
    />
    <link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/0.js" as="script" />
```

Opened issue on nuxt.js github page https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/10613

Comment: Did you tried that one? https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-router#prefetchpayloads

Comment: it is not applicable in my case.
1) I am using nuxt version 2.16.0
2) The problem is with preloaded chunks, not with prefetch
3) I don't want to disable that behaviour, I need to supply the required parameters such as "crossorigin" and "as" to the NUXT generated javascript chunks

Comment: 1. not sure how the version is blocking here 2. try that one so: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-render#resourcehints 3. valid point, I don't know further sorry.

Comment: @kissu FYI, this behaviour is a bug in NUXT Bridge's current version

Comment: Yeah, I saw the Github issue dw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is a bug in NUXT Bridge and will be fixed by NUXT when they upgrade to the new version of `vue-bundle-renderer`.

link to the issue: https://github.com/nuxt/bridge/issues/453